# Mongo query : aggregation, match, filter, project,

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

How then to retrieve all the users who have communicated with the page on the date entered from the front, the data structure below,

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "createdAt": "2019-02-20T21:34:17.634Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-03-01T20:47:55.100Z",
    "fullName": "Jennifer Lieutard",
    "firstName": "Jennifer",
    "lastName": "Lieutard",
    "conversations": [{
        "page": "1000",
        "messages": [
            {
            "content": "lorem ipsum",
            "date":  "2019-09-23T10:40:59.394Z"
            },
            {
             "content": "lorem not ipsum",
             "date": "2019-09-23T10:51:56.165Z"
            },
            {...}
        ]
    }]
    
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "createdAt": "2019-02-20T21:34:17.634Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-03-01T20:47:55.100Z",
    "fullName": "Peter Pan",
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Pan",
    "conversations": [{
        "page": "1001",
        "lastMessage": "Yes they can",
        "messages": [
            {
            "content": "lorem ipsum",
            "date":  "2019-09-23T10:40:59.394Z"
            },
            {
            "content": "lorem not ipsum",
            "date": "2019-09-23T10:51:56.165Z"
            },
            {...}
        ]
    }]
}
```

what i did

```
    const qMatch = {
        "conversations": {
          $elemMatch: { 
            "page": ObjectId(pageId),
          }
        }
    };

    const qLookup = {
      from: "messages",
      let: { comment_date: new Date("2019-12-13T13:56:06.225+00:00"),  formatedDate: {$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m", date: "$createdAt" }} },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr:
            { 
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$$comment_date", "$messages.date.0" ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "messages"
    };
```

I just want to retrieve the users who have communicated with page 1000 by comparing the date of the first message in the conversation with the date in YYYY-MM format entered from the front.

Comment: It sound like all is left is to group, like so  {$group: { _id: 0, res: { "$addToSet": "$fullName" } } } see: https://mongoplayground.net/p/uL6nucFW6JW

Comment: BTW,  "conversations" is an array of JSONs, but as far as I can understand from your example, it should be a JSON only, and the array is redundant there...And for dates comparison, I recommend using a range, not a single timestamp comparison

Comment: I don't fully understand the conditions for returning a user. "users who have communicated with the page on the date entered from the front" and "users who have communicated with page 1000 by comparing the date of the first message in the conversation" ...and then your code is comparing the date with `"createdAt"`.  These seem like 2 separate conditions.  Would you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is using a filter:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$match": {"conversations": {$elemMatch: {"page": "1000"}}}},
  {"$project": {conversations: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$conversations", 0]}, fullName: 1}},
  {"$project": {fullName: 1, items: {$filter: { input: "$conversations.messages",
          as: "item", cond: { $and: 
          [{$lte: [ "$$item.date", ISODate("2019-12-13T13:56:06.225+00:00")]},
           {$gt: [ "$$item.date", ISODate("2018-10-13T13:56:06.225+00:00")]}]}}}}},
  {"$addFields": {"sizeOf": { "$size": "$items" }}},
  {"$match": {sizeOf: { $gt: 0 }}},
  {"$group": {_id: 0, res: { "$addToSet": "$fullName"}}},
  {"$project": {res: 1,_id: 0}}
])
```

You can see an example here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/uL6nucFW6JW
Including the last $group stage that you asked for, and a time range filter.